LVM PV [unknown]
GI came across a very interesting (possibly) problem.
It seemed very strange to me, because it appeared after there was a double conflict with the UUID of new disks, fresh (I already solved it via vgimportclone).
Apparently one of my partners tried to make vgimportclone for VG above. Now I have an ambiguous picture.
I sincerely believe that PV and VG are made for each other. But pvs says the opposite.
Output pvs:
WARNING: Device for PV eLMcjf-O3Xz-1kcl-ugF4-7h2T-Ucgf-caNhKk not found or rejected by a filter.
WARNING: Device for PV mvH0q0-gzwW-HJG1-qxtD-aa2B-xKxW-XLHUtw not found or rejected by a filter.
WARNING: Device for PV vVNap3-bzCi-w2ia-bHYd-TMSf-yr3f-0uHxW2 not found or rejected by a filter.
WARNING: Device for PV vRgMgL-oAIh-biR7-wvCf-cBNT-L3su-n7Wfsh not found or rejected by a filter.
Couldn’t find device with uuid eLMcjf-O3Xz-1kcl-ugF4-7h2T-Ucgf-caNhKk.
Couldn’t find device with uuid mvH0q0-gzwW-HJG1-qxtD-aa2B-xKxW-XLHUtw.
Couldn’t find device with uuid vVNap3-bzCi-w2ia-bHYd-TMSf-yr3f-0uHxW2.
Couldn’t find device with uuid vRgMgL-oAIh-biR7-wvCf-cBNT-L3su-n7Wfsh.
WARNING: PV /dev/mapper/mpathg is marked in use but no VG was found using it.
WARNING: PV /dev/mapper/mpathg might need repairing.
WARNING: PV /dev/mapper/mpathf is marked in use but no VG was found using it.
WARNING: PV /dev/mapper/mpathf might need repairing.
WARNING: PV /dev/mapper/mpathh is marked in use but no VG was found using it.
WARNING: PV /dev/mapper/mpathh might need repairing.
WARNING: PV /dev/mapper/mpathe is marked in use but no VG was found using it.
WARNING: PV /dev/mapper/mpathe might need repairing.
PV        VG      Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
/dev/mapper/mpathe [unknown] lvm2 u–   2.25t 0
/dev/mapper/mpathf [unknown] lvm2 u–   2.25t 0
/dev/mapper/mpathg [unknown] lvm2 u–   2.25t 0
/dev/mapper/mpathh [unknown] lvm2 u–   2.25t 0
[unknown] vg1PDMs lvm2 a-m  <4.30t 0
[unknown] vg1PDMs lvm2 a-m  <4.30t 0
[unknown] vg1PDMs lvm2 a-m  <4.30t 0
[unknown] vg1PDMs lvm2 a-m  <4.30t 0

Part of command lsblk
sdcd 4.3T 0 disk
└─mpathh 4.3T 0 mpath
sdbw 4.3T 0 disk
└─mpathe 4.3T 0 mpath

Please tell me how to return lost disks to VG without data loss?
This is the feeling: what rubbish in the metadata. This is the first time I’ve encountered this.
PS-1.
Information from /etc/lvm/backup
pv0 {
    id = "eLMcjf-O3Xz-1kcl-ugF4-7h2T-Ucgf-caNhKk"
    device = "/dev/mapper/mpathy"
pv1 {
    id = "mvH0q0-gzwW-HJG1-qxtD-aa2B-xKxW-XLHUtw"
    device = "/dev/mapper/mpathv"
pv2 {
    id = "vVNap3-bzCi-w2ia-bHYd-TMSf-yr3f-0uHxW2"
    device = "/dev/mapper/mpathw"
pv3 {
    id = "vRgMgL-oAIh-biR7-wvCf-cBNT-L3su-n7Wfsh"
    device = "/dev/mapper/mpathx"

I found information about name and wwn bindings in /etc/multipath/bindings
mpathe 36742b0f000000be200000000000652a1
mpathf 36742b0f000000be200000000000652a7
mpathg 36742b0f000000be200000000000652a5
mpathh 36742b0f000000be200000000000652a3

And i find old bindings
mpathv 36742b0f000000be200000000000652a3
mpathw 36742b0f000000be200000000000652a1
mpathx 36742b0f000000be200000000000652a5
mpathy 36742b0f000000be200000000000652a7

Now I have information that can be compared, right?
Solution
pvcreate --restorefile /etc/lvm/backup/vg1PDMs --uuid eLMcjf-O3Xz-1kcl-ugF4-7h2T-Ucgf-caNhKk -ff /dev/mapper/mpathf
pvcreate --restorefile /etc/lvm/backup/vg1PDMs --uuid mvH0q0-gzwW-HJG1-qxtD-aa2B-xKxW-XLHUtw -ff /dev/mapper/mpathh
pvcreate --restorefile /etc/lvm/backup/vg1PDMs --uuid vVNap3-bzCi-w2ia-bHYd-TMSf-yr3f-0uHxW2 -ff /dev/mapper/mpathe
pvcreate --restorefile /etc/lvm/backup/vg1PDMs --uuid vRgMgL-oAIh-biR7-wvCf-cBNT-L3su-n7Wfsh -ff /dev/mapper/mpathg

Then vgchange -ay vg1PDMs and mount. Check fs is ok.
Thank you very much telcoM

Right. This is one output, broken into parts for ease of reading.

Edited for easier reading and wrote a question, thanks.

The PV names /dev/mapper/mpath* suggest you're using device-mapper-multipathing, which in turn suggests you are in some kind of a SAN environment. You also mention vgimportclone which suggests you are doing some sort of SAN-level snapshotting or cloning. Am I right?
If so, please use multipath -ll to verify the identity (usually WWID) of each PV, and figure out which of them actually are the originals and which are clones/snapshots. Verify that your idea matches the actual SAN configuration.
Then, if possible, remove the clones/snapshots from the system's view temporarily - that should help you to pick the correct disks, and it might allow the system to auto-detect the LVM volume group.
Then, run vgscan -vvv, to see if that is sufficient to fix things.
If not, you might have to restore the identities (PV UUIDs) of the PVs. If someone has made a mistake with vgimportclone, this is likely. Remember that there are backups of the current VG configuration in /etc/lvm/backup/ and some previous versions in /etc/lvm/archive/. The backup files are human-readable text files: you can read them to figure out which disk (or mpath device) has which PV UUID, and then re-assign them correctly. But you must be very careful.
To do that, use pvcreate --restorefile <backupfile.vg> --uuid <PV UUID> /dev/mapper/mpathX to adjust the PV UUID of a disk. Once all PVs belonging to the VG have their correct PV UUIDs, then use vgcfgrestore --file <backupfile.vg> to restore the rest of the VG configuration. If successful, you will then be able to activate the VG with vgchange -ay vg1PDMs. If you assigned the correct UUIDs to the correct disks, the data will be unharmed.
Once you get the originals to a stable working state, you can follow the same procedure with the snapshots/clones... or just re-snapshot/clone at the SAN level, as that might be faster and more straightforward.
If you need to present the snapshot/clone back to the same system that has the original VG, you must use the vgimportclone first thing after presenting the snapshot/clone, before you do anything else. And you must explicitly specify the complete set of the duplicate PVs (and none of the originals) to that command, otherwise confusion will result.

That's right, these disks are a clone. I checked multipath, there are only these 4 disks mpathe,f,g,h.
You are right, I looked in /etc/lvm/backup - there are disks mpathy,x,w,v
But I don't understand how to relate them. but I have a guess, I'll be back in a couple of minutes.

Am I understanding correctly?
That I have information and can execute commands.
Example: pvcreate --restorefile /etc/lvm/backup/vg1PDMs --uuid eLMcjf-O3Xz-1kcl-ugF4-7h2T-Ucgf-caNhKk /dev/mapper/mpathf
And so on in order, and then
vgcfgrestore --file /etc/lvm/backup/vg1PDMs
vgchange -ay vg1PDMs

Yes, it looks like you have all the correct information you'll need, and your understanding of the procedure is correct.

PV /dev/mapper/mpathf is used by a VG but its metadata is missing.
Can't initialize PV '/dev/mapper/mpathf' without -ff.
/dev/mapper/mpathf: physical volume not initialized.
--force --force use
Am I understanding correctly? That the volume has already been initialized and needs to be forced to start. I'm a little scared)

Yes, the purpose of this operation is to first restore the correct PV UUIDs, and since the disks/LUNs contain a recognizable PV header, it requires double force. The vgcfgrestore step will then restore the rest of the VG metadata, but it needs the PV UUIDs in place first.

In my case. It was enough to change uuid pv with -ff and vgchange -ay. Thank you very much, marked as answer.

Great, then the problem must have been exactly that the PV UUIDs were confused, and the rest of the metadata was intact. This very much looks like the result of a messed-up vgimportclone; maybe it's time to check with your partners that all are aware of the correct SAN clone/snapshot procedures and understand them (and the consequences of getting them wrong)? Also, if the timestamp of your /etc/multipath/bindings file is newer than your current initramfs file, update the initramfs file, just to be safe (to eliminate the faintest possibility of conflict if multipathed disks activate early).
